# DockerCompose (NetLogo + ROS) - Copiando Java de um build para outro

Tags: docker

Sou iniciante com o Docker e preciso de ajuda para colocar duas imagens juntas.

Primeiro, eu tenho esses arquivos Dockerfile / docker-compose, para um Docker Container com ROS. Sozinho, funciona bem.

Dockerfile:

```
ARG FROM_IMAGE=ros:foxy
ARG OVERLAY_WS=/opt/ros/overlay_ws

# multi-stage for caching
FROM $FROM_IMAGE AS cacher

# clone overlay source
ARG OVERLAY_WS
WORKDIR $OVERLAY_WS/src
RUN echo "\
repositories: \n\
  ros2/codigo_gustavo: \n\
    type: git \n\
    url: https://github.com/GustavoLLima/codigo_gustavo.git \n\
    version: master \n\
" > ../overlay.repos
RUN vcs import ./ < ../overlay.repos

# copy manifests for caching
WORKDIR /opt
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/opt && \
    find ./ -name "package.xml" | \
      xargs cp --parents -t /tmp/opt && \
    find ./ -name "COLCON_IGNORE" | \
      xargs cp --parents -t /tmp/opt || true

# multi-stage for building
FROM $FROM_IMAGE AS builder

# install overlay dependencies
ARG OVERLAY_WS
WORKDIR $OVERLAY_WS
COPY --from=cacher /tmp/$OVERLAY_WS/src ./src
RUN . /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.sh && \
    apt-get update && rosdep install -y \
      --from-paths \
        src \
      --rosdistro \
        foxy \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# build overlay source
COPY --from=cacher $OVERLAY_WS/src ./src
ARG OVERLAY_MIXINS="release"
RUN . /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.sh && \
    colcon build \
      --packages-select \
        codigo_gustavo \
      --mixin $OVERLAY_MIXINS

# source entrypoint setup
ENV OVERLAY_WS $OVERLAY_WS
RUN sed --in-place --expression \
      '$isource "$OVERLAY_WS/install/setup.bash"' \
      /ros_entrypoint.sh
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  talker:
    build: ./
    command: ros2 run codigo_gustavo talker

  listener:
    build: ./
    environment:
      - "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1"
    command: ros2 run codigo_gustavo listener
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
```

Depois, eu tenho outros arquivos Dockerfile / Docker-Compose para um Docker Container executando o NetLogo. Novamente, sozinho funciona bem.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk
LABEL maintainer="Allen Lee <allen.lee@asu.edu>"

ARG NETLOGO_HOME=/opt/netlogo
ARG NETLOGO_VERSION=6.0.4

ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    NETLOGO_TARBALL=NetLogo-$NETLOGO_VERSION-64.tgz

ENV NETLOGO_URL=https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/$NETLOGO_VERSION/$NETLOGO_TARBALL

WORKDIR /opt
RUN wget $NETLOGO_URL && tar xzf $NETLOGO_TARBALL && ln -sf "NetLogo $NETLOGO_VERSION" netlogo \
    && rm -f $NETLOGO_TARBALL
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  modelo1:
    build: ./
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    volumes:
      - ./teste:/teste

volumes:
  teste:
```

Agora o problema: estou tentando colocar esses dois códigos juntos, para usar apenas um arquivo Dockerfile / Docker-Compose, tornando-o mais fácil de executar. O problema é que consegui fazer os dois containers, mas quando tento rodar o NetLogo (via netlogo headless), o Container não consegue encontrar o Java (dependência do NetLogo). Verifiquei o diretório e parece que o Java não está instalado. O workspace vem com duas pastas, NetLogo e ROS.

Dockerfile:

```
#--------------Netlogo Instalation--------------
ARG FROM_IMAGE=ros:foxy
ARG OVERLAY_WS=/opt/ros/overlay_ws

#FROM openjdk:8-jdk AS netlogo_cache
FROM openjdk:8-jdk
LABEL maintainer="Allen Lee <allen.lee@asu.edu>"

ARG NETLOGO_HOME=/opt/netlogo
ARG NETLOGO_VERSION=6.0.4

ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    NETLOGO_TARBALL=NetLogo-$NETLOGO_VERSION-64.tgz

ENV NETLOGO_URL=https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/$NETLOGO_VERSION/$NETLOGO_TARBALL

WORKDIR /opt
RUN wget $NETLOGO_URL && tar xzf $NETLOGO_TARBALL && ln -sf "NetLogo $NETLOGO_VERSION" netlogo \
    && rm -f $NETLOGO_TARBALL



#--------------ROS------------------------

#ARG FROM_IMAGE=ros:foxy
#ARG OVERLAY_WS=/opt/ros/overlay_ws

# multi-stage for caching
FROM $FROM_IMAGE AS cacher

# clone overlay source
ARG OVERLAY_WS
WORKDIR $OVERLAY_WS/src
RUN echo "\
repositories: \n\
  ros2/codigo_gustavo: \n\
    type: git \n\
    url: https://github.com/GustavoLLima/codigo_gustavo.git \n\
    version: master \n\
" > ../overlay.repos
RUN vcs import ./ < ../overlay.repos

# copy manifests for caching
WORKDIR /opt
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/opt && \
    find ./ -name "package.xml" | \
      xargs cp --parents -t /tmp/opt && \
    find ./ -name "COLCON_IGNORE" | \
      xargs cp --parents -t /tmp/opt || true

# multi-stage for building
FROM $FROM_IMAGE AS builder

# install overlay dependencies
ARG OVERLAY_WS
WORKDIR $OVERLAY_WS
COPY --from=cacher /tmp/$OVERLAY_WS/src ./src
RUN . /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.sh && \
    apt-get update && rosdep install -y \
      --from-paths \
        src \
      --rosdistro \
        foxy \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# build overlay source
COPY --from=cacher $OVERLAY_WS/src ./src
ARG OVERLAY_MIXINS="release"
RUN . /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.sh && \
    colcon build \
      --packages-select \
        codigo_gustavo \
      --mixin $OVERLAY_MIXINS

# source entrypoint setup
ENV OVERLAY_WS $OVERLAY_WS
RUN sed --in-place --expression \
      '$isource "$OVERLAY_WS/install/setup.bash"' \
      /ros_entrypoint.sh

#COPY --from=netlogo_cache /opt/netlogo ./netlogo
COPY --from=0 /opt/netlogo ./netlogo
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  talker:
    build: ./
    command: ros2 run codigo_gustavo talker

  listener:
    build: ./
    environment:
      - "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1"
    command: ros2 run codigo_gustavo listener
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2

  modelo1:
    build: ./
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    volumes:
      - ./teste:/teste

volumes:
  teste:
```

Contexto do erro:

```
cd /opt/ros/overlay_ws
./netlogo/netlogo-headless.sh --model /teste/WS2.nlogo --experiment experiment1 --spreadsheet /teste/teste2.csv
JAVA_HOME undefined, using java from path. For control over exact java version, set JAVA_HOME
./netlogo/netlogo-headless.sh: line43: java: command not found
```

Alguma ideia? O que devo fazer? O que estou fazendo errado?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara os Dockerfiles tem q ser separado mesmo. Vc vai referenciar cada um no docker-compose. Ficaria assim:

```
version: '3'

services:
  talker:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ros.dockerfile
    command: ros2 run codigo_gustavo talker

  listener:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: netlogo.dockerfile
    environment:
      - "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1"
    command: ros2 run codigo_gustavo listener
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2

  modelo1:
    build: ./
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    volumes:
      - ./teste:/teste

volumes:
  teste:
```

Vc só precisa encadear o context e dockerfile na diretiva build, então vc vai poder passar o local do Dockerfile.